# The domain does not open when proxying to a uwsgi socket via nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

- My server is deployed on the Amazon EC2 cloud.
- Operating system Ubuntu 22.04

I have a simple uwsgi application with venvironment. I saved the project in the home folder, sudo user ubuntu. For the test I used simple code:

```python
def application(environ, start_response):
   start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
   return [b"<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"]
```

First, I launched the application in environment for testing with this command:

`uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8080 --protocol=http -w main`

In the instance security groups (on AWS), I opened port 8080 temporarily to check that everything was working. And it really worked.

Next I created this config:

```service
[uwsgi]
socket = main.sock
chmod-socket = 664
protocol = http
module = main
chdir = /home/ubuntu/operatorAPI
master = true
processes = 5
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
logto = /home/ubuntu/operatorAPI/log/uwsgi_operator_api.log
```

Then I created service `/etc/systemd/system/operator_api.service`:

```service
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve operator api
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/operatorAPI
Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/operatorAPI/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/operatorAPI/venv/bin/uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And also created a config for nginx.

```nginx
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name uniapi.example.com;

   access_log /home/ubuntu/operatorAPI/log/nginx_access.log; 
   error_log /home/ubuntu/operatorAPI/log/nginx_error.log;


    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/ubuntu/operatorAPI/main.sock;
    }
}
```

Then I restart nginx, started the service and checked to log in to the domain. It didn't work out. And in the nginx log I read this:

```
2023/11/22 12:56:03 [crit] 48800#48800: *126 connect() to unix:/home/ubuntu/operatorAPI/main.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: *****, server: uniapi.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/ubuntu/operatorAPI/main.sock:", host: "uniapi.example.com"
```

Since the nginx log shows this, it means my domain is pointing correctly to my server (I specifically replaced the domain address with this because I don’t want to show it on stackoverflow)

I checked that the socket is indeed created at the specified address. Write permission 664.

Then, to test whether the service really works, I decided to change the uwsgi setting and instead of the socket set the address 0.0.0.0:44444. I opened a port in EC2.

```service
[uwsgi]
socket = 0.0.0.0:44444
protocol = http
module = main
chdir = /home/ubuntu/operatorAPI
master = true
processes = 5
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
logto = /home/ubuntu/operatorAPI/log/uwsgi_operator_api.log
```

And after that I restarted the service and logged in by IP and port. Everything worked.

In nginx I replaced this `uwsgi_pass 0.0.0.0:44444;`

But I still can’t access this by domain. Only for bare IP and port.

I also changed user in service to root but it's not helped.

**P.S.**
The most interesting thing is that I already did something similar on another hosting (not Amazon), and it all worked there. Maybe something additional needs to be done on Amazon?

Comment: Which user and group the nginx process runs as? Do they have access to all the directories on the way to the socket? Do your distribution/filesystem have extended ACL or SELinux enabled?

Comment: in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf user  www-data. It's wrong? The socket is launched by the service as a root user with the group www-data

Comment: @Quassnoi ACL or SELinux not installed

Comment: In this path: `/home/ubuntu/operatorAPI`, what is the owner of every directory, and what the permissions are on this directory? In Linux, to be able to open a file, the process needs the execute permission on every directory in the file's path.

Comment: @Quassnoi home is root:root. And folder ubuntu owned by ubuntu:ubuntu. operatorAPI - ubuntu:www-data

Comment: @Quassnoi I just tried setting `user root` in nginx.conf; and it worked, I was finally able to log in through the domain. But is this good practice?

Comment: No, it's not. You should put your socket into a directory accessible by www-data. Better yet, don't run uwcgi as root either

Comment: @Quassnoi I tried to re-create the folder in `/home/ubuntu` and repeated all the steps, but this time I assigned the owner not to `ubuntu:www-data`, but to `ubuntu:ubuntu` for all the files in the folder. I also set the user and group `ubuntu` in the service. In this case, when I returned `user www-data` in `nginx.conf`, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

In POSIX-compatible file systems, to open a file, the process needs to have the execute permission (`x`) on all the directories in the file's path, starting from the root directory (`/`).

In stock Ubuntu distributions used by EC2, `/home/ubuntu/` is the home directory for the user `ubuntu`. By default, like all home directories, it's owned by `ubuntu:ubuntu`, and doesn't give any permissions to the others.

UWSGI process is setuid to `ubuntu`, so it can traverse the directories and open the socket.

Nginx process is setiud to `www-data:www-data`, so it doesn't have execute permissions on `/home/ubuntu`, and, hence, on no directories or files underneath it.

Placing Unix sockets to home directories is a bad idea. According to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s15.html), the sockets should go to `/run` or a subdirectory thereof:

> System programs that maintain transient UNIX-domain sockets must place them in this directory or an appropriate subdirectory as outlined above.

`/run` is a transient, root only-writable directory on standard-conforming distributions:

> This directory contains system information data describing the system since it was booted. Files under this directory must be cleared (removed or truncated as appropriate) at the beginning of the boot process.
>
> /run should not be writable for unprivileged users; it is a major security problem if any user can write in this directory. User-specific subdirectories should be writable only by each directory's owner.

Note that even though the standard says "files", in practice many distributions mount it on tmpfs (in-memory filesystem), which makes also the directories (not just files) vanish upon reboot.

To use it for sockets, you'll to recreate it on boot.

One way to do that is to create an entry in [`/etc/tmpfiles.d`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/tmpfiles.d.5.html) that would create a subfolder writable by `www-data` every time the system boots, and place your socket under this subfolder.

Alternatively, if you want to keep everything in systemd, add a [RuntimeDirectory](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.exec.html#RuntimeDirectory=) entry to your service definition.

Comment: I tried to create a socket in the /run directory, but it is not created there, since only root can create there

Comment: @cheerful_weasel: see the update